# Знак вопросительный в риторическом вопросе

Tags: пунктуация, поэзия, вопросительный-знак

Как правильно оформить эти строчки из «Песни мушкетёров», спетой Боярским? Это же риторический вопрос всё-таки.

> Куда вас, судаpь, к чёpту занесло? / Hеужто вам покой — не по каpману?

> Куда вас, судаpь, к чёpту занесло.  / Hеужто вам покой — не по каpману.

[Песня](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKEpYJOOD0E)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Вечер до-обрый, можно сказать, добрющий, Артём! Давненько не пересекались. *...строчки **песни «Песня** мушкетёров»...* А не лучше ли без повторов? Вот так: *строчки из «Песни мушкетёров»*.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Привет, Рим! Рад слышать тебя! Ну я просто сокращение убрал, а остальное не смотрел, вопрос-то не мой. А так ты права — вперёд! :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Я думаю, что ответ имеется в [Справочнике по пунктуации](https://gramota.ru/biblioteka/spravochniki/spravochnik-po-punktuatsii/k-chertu):

> **К ЧЕРТУ,** в сочетании с местоименными словами
> Слова «к черту», употребляемые для усиления иронической или риторической интонации вопросительных местоимений и наречий «какой», «куда» и др., к которым они относятся, чаще выделяются запятыми. <...>
> ***Куда** вас, сударь, **к черту,** занесло? // Неужто вам покой не по карману?* Ю. Ряшенцев, Песенка мушкетеров.
> @ В художественной литературе встречаются примеры невыделения запятыми слов «к черту» в аналогичном контексте: ***Какие** тут к **черту** гипнотизеры!* М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. ***Какой** там **к черту** отвод?* Ю. Домбровский, Хранитель древностей.

• Вопросительные знаки ставим (риторический вопрос — это фигура речи, представляющая собой **вопрос**, на который ответа не ожидается).

• Тире во втором предложении, считаю, не нужно.
*Не по карману* — разговорное устойчивое сочетание, использовано в значении *не по средствам, слишком до́рог*.

P. S. Обособлять или нет "к черту"? Это уже авторское решение.
Вот ещё пример без запятых:
*Ну **куда** тебя **к черту** понесло — самоубийца!* (Василий Шукшин. Пьедестал).

[Риторический вопрос](https://literaturologiya.academic.ru/600/%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81)

P. P. S. Трудно сказать, оригинал это стихов или нет, но в [Нотном Архиве России](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/dunaevskiymaxim/stranizi/Pesnyamushketerov.html) есть вот такой текст, в котором вопросительные знаки имеются, "к черту" обособлено и "странное" тире отсутствует (слова Ю. Ряшенцева, музыка М. Дунаевского):

*Опять скрипит потертое седло,

И ветер холодит былую рану.

Куда вас, сударь, к черту, занесло?

Неужто вам покой не по карману?*